# Horror movie where cars won't start once turned off

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

The movie came out around the same time as The Evil Dead (1981), so it probably came out between 1976 to 1986.  It is an American film, in English and in live action and color, and it mostly takes place in Texas or a desert type of area.  I watched it on VHS.

In the film a group of college students (both men and women) visit a place in a desert-like area.  A little girl, presumably a witch, is shown pointing a bone towards their cars from far away while standing on top of a mountain.

When the students reach their destination and turn their cars off, they will not restart.  There's a scene where a second car from the group arrives later, they try to keep the driver from turning the car off, but since he can't hear them over the music he turns it off and it wouldn't restart.

The students can't leave the place, and they use a book to cast a protection spell on the place.  Later on a topless girl from their group tries to entice them to leave the spell of the protected cabin.

There's also a scene where the spirit of a priest or holy figure shows up.  The demons convince the holy figure to "take them" and they combine into a big demon or some such.

There might also be a scene where a priest is standing and when he turns his back towards the camera he is naked from the back.

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! We have a minimum requirement for ID questions on this site. Do you remember when/where/how you watched this movie? What language was it in? Was it an American production, or from a different country? Was it real life or animated? Was it in color? We'll need answers to these questions to help us track down an answer to this question.  If you have this information, please edit it into your question.

Comment: edited to provide more info

Comment: Okay, the horror revolves around being stranded and other stuff happening. I was thinking that cars not starting would be awfully specific to a car enthusiast audience to have broad horror-appeal.  :D

Answer (score 4):

Its the "[Demon Wind](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099401/)" (1990) - I've seen it as a kid and gave me nightmares for weeks:

Here are fragments of the movie(**warning kids!, its a horror!!!**)

> In the film a group of college students (both men and women) visit a place in a desert-like area.

It was a farm-like building with a big shed. What is quite interesting, from the front you can see the whole building, but one character goes behind it and sees that it is only a front wall. There is inscription written on the wall that starts the whole mayhem.

> A little girl, presumably a witch, is shown pointing a bone towards their cars from far away while standing on top of a mountain.

You can see her at the first seconds of the fragments above. She also shows up (as a last surviving monster) in the very end of the movie.

> When the students reach their destination and turn their cars off, they will not restart.

Checked.

> The students can't leave the place, and they use a book to cast a protection spell on the place.

There is a magical book and a few magical daggers - the book protects the house but later on protection fades. Daggers have the ability to free the soul trapped inside the monsters.

> There's also a scene where the spirit of a priest or holy figure shows up. The demons convince the holy figure to "take them" and they combine into a big demon or some such.

Indeed: towards the end of the movie a priest walks from the barn addressing the monsters as his children. Then they are joined together into one huge monster that is able to break the protection spell. To counter this, the main character turns (via spell) into angelic-like figure.

Comment: Yep, horrifying.

Comment: @BrettFromLA It was for me when I was 11 :P

Comment: is that last video an official upload? full movie uploads to youtube are not automatically given the free pass to piracy as such if that is not an official upload by the studio it should be removed from the answer